# Are elements with an identical "order" value valid?

Tags: css, duplicates, flexbox

I am using the CSS `order` property to reorder elements in a flexbox container.

There are some elements I would like to put at the end of this list, so I am using `order: 1000`, which is higher than the order of anything else by far.

I do not care about the order of these "end" elements relative to each other, but I'm not sure if having a whole bunch of elements with `order: 1000` is valid.

I can't find anything about it in the spec. Is this valid/legal?

Comment: Since the `order` property accepts integers, wouldn't it be fair to say that any integer would be acceptable? By default the `order` property has a value of `0`, so if you are asking if multiple elements with the same `order` integer is acceptable, wouldn't the answer be yes?

Comment: "Valid/legal" in what sense?

Comment: @torazaburo: I'm thinking something in the same vein as CSS table layout - one would say that a display: table-row box can never "legally" have any other parent box than a table box or a row-group box - and an anonymous one will be created if necessary (since CSS can't point at your stylesheet and say "that's not valid - you have a display: table-row declaration but not a display: table declaration").

Comment: @BoltClock *an anonymous one will be created if necessary* Are you sure about that? I know a `tbody` will be created between a `table` and `tr`, but this doesn't seem to apply to any element just because it has the `table-row` value for the `display` property.

Comment: @torazaburo: Yes, see [§17.2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes). Note that elements and boxes are not the same thing. An element or pseudo-element that is not display: none can generate one or more boxes, but not every box corresponds to an element or pseudo-element - those that don't are usually anonymous boxes. Although the CSS table model is largely based on that of HTML, this is entirely a feature of CSS and is independent of any document language rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is never a situation in CSS in which multiple elements sharing the same value for a property are considered "invalid". CSS does not define validity in this way. As justinw mentions in the comments, since every element has at least the initial value for every CSS property unless otherwise specified by browser defaults or you, CSS needs to account for this scenario for every single property.

In the case of the `order` property, two flex items with the same value are laid out according to source order, as stated [in section 5.4 of the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#order-property). That is to say, between two flex items with `order: 1000` (or two flex items with `order: 1`, or even the initial value `0` for that matter), the one that comes first in the source markup (assuming the DOM tree hasn't been manipulated after the fact) will be laid out before the one that comes last, according to the direction specified by `flex-direction`.

Here's the exact quote:

> Items with the same ordinal group are laid out in the order they appear in the source document. This also affects the [painting order](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html) [CSS21], exactly as if the flex items were reordered in the source document.

This is similar to how two elements with the same computed value for `z-index` are painted back-to-front in source order (see [section 9.9 of CSS2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers)).

Answer (score 2):

> Are elements with an identical `order` value valid?

Yes. In fact, all flex items have an identical `order` value by default. An initial setting of a flex container is `order: 0`. This means that all flex items, whether one or 1000, will have the same `order` value until overridden.

> I do not care about the order of these "end" elements relative to each other, but I'm not sure if having a whole bunch of elements with `order: 1000` is valid.

If you're talking about hitting the upper limit of possible `order` values, you can safely assume there is none. What if you have 5,000 flex items in the container?

There is no legal limit to the number of elements that can exist in a container. So there can't be a limit to the `order` value. With 5,000 items, `order: 5000` must be available.